# Map function to show the data received from fetch function is not working

Tags: reactjs, arrays, api, components, jsx

I am a beginner in writing React applications. Please help me where I have gone wrong in writing the code. This is the API- https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json. I am not able to iterate over the json format that I have received from fetch function. Below is the code.

```
//import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  
  const[bitData, setbitData]=useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json",{
    method:'GET'
  }).then(result=>result.json())
  .then(result=>setbitData(result))    
  },[]) 
  
  return (
    <div className="App">      
      { bitData &&       
      <table className="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Code</th>
          <th scope="col">Symbol</th>
          <th scope="col">Rate</th>
          <th scope="col">Description</th>
          <th scope="col">Rate_float</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>   
       
        
          {
          bitData.map(draw=>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">{draw.code}</th>
            <td>{draw.symbol}</td>
            <td>{draw.rate}</td>
            <td>{draw.description}</td>
          </tr>
        )}        
       
      </tbody>
    </table>        

      }      
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

This is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: bitData.map is not a function
    at App (App.js:28:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1)
App @ App.js:28
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateFunctionComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19588
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21601
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `bitData` is a JSON object. you can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the actual values in it.

Try like below:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [bitData, setbitData] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json", {
      method: "GET"
    })
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .then((result) => setbitData(result));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {bitData && (
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Code</th>
              <th scope="col">Symbol</th>
              <th scope="col">Rate</th>
              <th scope="col">Description</th>
              <th scope="col">Rate_float</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {bitData &&
              Object.values(bitData.bpi).map(
                ({ code, symbol, rate, description, rate_float }) => (
                  <tr key={code}>
                    <th scope="row">{code}</th>
                    <td>{symbol}</td>
                    <td>{rate}</td>
                    <td>{description}</td>
                    <td>{rate_float}</td>
                  </tr>
                )
              )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

#### Explanation

`Object.values(bitData.bpi)` gives the list of values of the JSON input. And in your case value is again an object with the format like:

```json
{ code: "", symbol: "", rate: "", description: "", rate_float: "" }
```

So then we can destructure these JSON properties in the input of `map` function.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. But I am unable to figure out the parameters that you mentioned inside map function. Did you destructure the array? Please explain.

Comment: @DesaiVibha, yes I have destructured a single item of the output of Object.values. I will add some description.

Answer (score 1):

The API link you are using returns a JSON response (JavaScript Object Notations), but the `.map()` function is used for arrays.

From your code and the JSON provided by the API I believe you are trying to reach the elements under the `bpi`.

I edited the last `.then` method in your fetch request so you can get an array in `bitData` instead of an object:

```js
fetch("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json",{
    method:'GET'
  }).then(result=>result.json())
  .then(result=>setbitData(Object.values(result.bpi)))
```